# Changing the value of one column based on another in r

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following data, and I want to change the values in the count column to negative if the text in 'Color' is Yellow. I tried mutate_if with no success. How can I go about doing so if I want to:

1. Replace the values in count with the new negative values, or
2. Create a new column with the name Count_final with new negative values, as well as the same old values for the entries that are not yellow?

Thank you.

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Color,    ~Item, ~Count,       ~Year,
    "Blue",    "Bag",     50, "2009-2011",
    "Blue", "Wallet",     60, "2009-2011",
   "Green",  "Shoes",     80, "2009-2011",
   "Green",  "Shirt",     90, "2009-2011",
  "Yellow", "Flower",     20, "2009-2011",
  "Yellow",   "Bees",     30, "2009-2011",
    "Blue",    "Bag",     50, "2009-2011",
    "Blue", "Wallet",     60, "2009-2011",
   "Green",  "Shoes",     90, "2009-2011",
   "Green",  "Shirt",     20, "2009-2011",
  "Yellow", "Flower",     10, "2009-2011",
  "Yellow",   "Bees",      5, "2009-2011"
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can multiply `Count` with 1 (to keep the value as it is) if `Color` is not `"Yellow"` and -1 if `Color` is `"Yellow"`. This can be achieved directly with

```
data$Count_final <- with(data, Count * c(1, -1)[(Color == "Yellow") + 1])

# A tibble: 12 x 5
#   Color  Item   Count Year      Count_final
#   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 Blue   Bag       50 2009-2011          50
# 2 Blue   Wallet    60 2009-2011          60
# 3 Green  Shoes     80 2009-2011          80
# 4 Green  Shirt     90 2009-2011          90
# 5 Yellow Flower    20 2009-2011         -20
# 6 Yellow Bees      30 2009-2011         -30
# 7 Blue   Bag       50 2009-2011          50
# 8 Blue   Wallet    60 2009-2011          60
# 9 Green  Shoes     90 2009-2011          90
#10 Green  Shirt     20 2009-2011          20
#11 Yellow Flower    10 2009-2011         -10
#12 Yellow Bees       5 2009-2011          -5
```

Or with simple `if_else`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(Count_final = Count * if_else(Color == "Yellow", -1, 1))
```

Or as @Kent Johnson suggested -

```
data %>% mutate(Count_final = if_else(Color=='Yellow', -Count, Count))
```

Comment: Or without the multiplication: `mutate(Count_final = if_else(Color=='Yellow', -Count, Count))`

Comment: @KentJohnson thanks..that's a valid suggestion too. Updated the answer.